# How to __Scrape__ Comment Section Content Which Cannot Be Found in Both HTML Content and AJAX Response

Tags: python, xmlhttprequest, web-crawler

As in topic, I would like to crawl the comments on the website under "Project Activity" section: https://www.donorschoose.org/project/social-distancing-in-kindergarten/5025093/?context=false

However, what I don't understand is that the content text can neither be found in plain HTML and the response from XHR calls.

That's the end of my knowledge and I have no idea what to do beyond the two tricks above, and I am a bit lost as to where exactly those texts come from and in what way then can I crawl them. Can someone enlighten me on that?

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script to load the comments from external URL:

```
import re
import json
import requests


url = 'https://www.donorschoose.org/project/social-distancing-in-kindergarten/5025093/?context=false'
comments_url = 'https://cdn.donorschoose.net/dwr/jsonp/ProposalMessageWebService/getProposalMessagesByProposalId?callback=projectTimelineCallback&param0={id}&context=false'


id_ = re.search(r'/(\d+)/', url).group(1)
text = requests.get(comments_url.format(id=id_)).text
text = re.search(r'\((.*)\)', text).group(1)
data = json.loads( re.sub(r'new Date\((\d+)\)', r'\1', text) )

# uncomment this to see all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

# print some info to screen:
for t in data['data']['threads']:
    print(t['original']['author']['firstName'])
    print(t['original']['message'])
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Stephanie
purchased the <a href="#materials"><span>resources</span></a> for Ms. Carway's classroom and notified the school principal of delivery
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Maree
<a href="#letter"><img alt="Teacher Mail" src="https://cdn.donorschoose.net/images/project/posted_mail.gif"><span>Thank You Letter</span></a> posted!
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Maree
<strong class='good-news'>Good news: Project fully funded!</strong>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```

Comment: Hi! May I know how you found the comment_url link? it is apparently correct but I cannot find it in the html source code. That's impressive. https://cdn.donorschoose.net/dwr/jsonp/ProposalMessageWebService/getProposalMessagesByProposalId?callback=projectTimelineCallback&param0={id}&context=false

Comment: @BoscoTsin When you open Firefox Developer Tools -> Network Tab you can see, where the page is making requests. One of these requests is this link. (Chrome has something similar for developers)

Comment: ok i see, i was expecting to see the comments directly from the "response" tab maybe in json format or so and I found none. that's where i got stuck. They are there under the preview tab...